# Get those rows in MySql whose selling price has been changed for a particular location

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 1000s of rows, out of those rows I want to filter based on some parameters.
Below mentioned is my query

```
SELECT product, selling_price, location FROM tablename ORDER BY product, location
```

The above query returns the below data

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| product      | selling_price  | location             |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product A    | 1.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product A    | 1.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product B    | 1.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product B    | 2.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product C    | 1.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product C    | 1.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product C    | 2.00           | location 2           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product C    | 2.00           | location 2           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product D    | 3.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product D    | 4.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product D    | 4.00           | location 2           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product D    | 4.00           | location 2           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
```

I want to edit the above query so that I get the below mentioned output.

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| product      | selling_price  | location             |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product B    | 1.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product B    | 2.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product D    | 3.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
| Product D    | 4.00           | location 1           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------------+
```

i.e only those rows whose price has been changed for same location should appear in this case price of Product B and Product D has changed in a particular location.

I tried to add `HAVING COUNT(product) > 1` but then it is returning on only row.

this [Display only those rows, whose SUM(price) is more than a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342565/display-only-those-rows-whose-sumprice-is-more-than-a-certain-number) suggests adding `HAVING` clause but it is only applicable to `GROUP BY`

Other link [MYSQL query - get rows where price is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655513/mysql-query-get-rows-where-price-is-changed) is very close to what I want, what the reply is not very clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why product C isn't in the output though it changed from 1 to 2?

Comment: Since he is looking for only `location 1`

Comment: @stickybit as correctly stated by @James, `Product C` didn't change in a particular location, if it would have been changed in any particular location then it should also appear, irrespective of `location 1` or `location 2`

Comment: What about newly added products? Do those need to be seen as a "changed" price.

Comment: @RaymondNijland no only the existing products need to be seen as a "changed" price

Comment: *"no only the existing products need to be see as a "changed" price "* Well a new product is also a existing product, you most likely mean the product needs atleast has to have two records.

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are correct; must have atleast two records.

Comment: what if Product A has three records do you need to have all three records in the results? See mine [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYSLLA3A4voRxeKuUpx8M6/3) example.  Which i also placed as a answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes all the three records

Comment: *"yes all the three records"* Then iam afraid @forpas 's query isn't the correct answer for what you really want ot need.  His query is more suited if you need to have the old and new price only as it will not give all records from a "group"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195121/discussion-between-abbas-and-raymond-nijland).

Comment: *"I checked forpas query, it is returning more than two records."* as you already left form the chat and i was gone for a while consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYSLLA3A4voRxeKuUpx8M6/5) .. i forgot to mention that it only will select unique records form a "group" so if a price has 1 first then 2 and the 1 again you will miss a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i most likely would go for

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 tablename
WHERE
 (product, location) IN (

  SELECT 
     product
   , location
  FROM 
   tablename 
  GROUP BY 
     product
   , location
  HAVING 
    MIN(selling_price) <> MAX(selling_price)

)
ORDER BY 
   product
 , location
```

**Result**

```
| product   | selling_price | location   |
| --------- | ------------- | ---------- |
| Product B | 1             | location 1 |
| Product B | 2             | location 1 |
| Product D | 3             | location 1 |
| Product D | 4             | location 1 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYSLLA3A4voRxeKuUpx8M6/2)

Answer (score 4):

A self join will do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.product, t1.selling_price, t1.location 
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t1.product = t2.product AND t1.location = t2.location AND t1.selling_price <> t2.selling_price 
ORDER BY t1.product, t1.location, t1.selling_price
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYSLLA3A4voRxeKuUpx8M6/1).
Results:

```
| product   | selling_price    | location   |
| --------- | ---------------- | ---------- |
| Product B | 1.00             | location 1 |
| Product B | 2.00             | location 1 |
| Product D | 3.00             | location 1 |
| Product D | 4.00             | location 1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EXISTS` that checks for any other record with the same product and location but a different price. Use `DISTINCT` to eliminate possible duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.product,
       t1.selling_price,
       t1.location
       FROM tablename t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM tablename t2
                            WHERE t2.procuct = t1.product
                                  AND t2.location = t1.location
                                  AND t2.selling_price <> t1.selling_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    product, selling_price, location
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    product IN (SELECT 
            t.product
        FROM
            tablename t
        GROUP BY t.product , t.location
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            AND (SELECT 
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                tablename t2
            WHERE
                t2.product = t.product
                    AND t2.location = t.location
            GROUP BY t2.selling_price) > 1)
ORDER BY product , location
```

Comment: this query is not what the topicstarter is looking for..   this query simply is selecting duplicates it does not compare/fetch price changes.

Comment: mmm...i was sure that would work . By the way it's inspiring the solution you give ... :/